# How do I take advantage of Next.js server-side rendering while using React hooks extensively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I've recently started working on a frontend project that uses Next.js, and I'm trying to figure out how to best take advantage of the SSR it provides. I want to use some client-side fetching as well, and while the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/learn/foundations/how-nextjs-works/rendering) explains that using React hooks in a component will make it render client-side, it seems quite sparse about how this affects the other components up/down the DOM tree.

I tried to test the SSR/CSR behaviour by creating a site with some components with/without React hooks in them, and opening it in Chrome first with JavaScript enabled, then disabled. So far I've found out a couple of things and I was wondering if my assumptions are right:

- it seems that components that use hooks work like typical React components - their children re-render when effect/state hooks in the parent render, so they don't seem to benefit from SSR and should instead be optimised using React features like `React.memo`.
- when I open the site with JS disabled, it seems that all components come pre-rendered - components that use state and display it, even show the initial state set in the hook. For example, the below component:

```
export const TestComponent = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(13)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setNum(num+1)}>CLICK</button>
      <h2>Number: {num}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

actually contains the text "**Number: 13**" (the button obviously doesn't work without JS though)

What I'm also wondering is how much using global context providers is going to diminish performance improvement from SSR. Let's say my `_app.jsx` wraps each page in a provider that periodically queries an API. Does it completely void the advantage presented by SSR, seeing as it will probably cause the entire page to re-render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of SSR as first paint data, and what is the trigger for it. Anything that causes the trigger for SSR to run, you will be getting data from `getServerSideProps`

SSR is usually done for SEO purposes so the bot can crawl the pre-rendered data. Any data that is depended on client-side fetch will be less prone for crawling.

Let's say for a shopping page, the initial products load can be SSR while subsequent products on clicking of a 'Load More' button happens on client side with the `useSWR` hook. This is a valid approach, and it mixes both SSR and CSR.

If a provider queries the API, that is a client side fetch. It won't coincide with what SSR is doing. It's important to know the trigger for SSR, which usually happens on a first visit, reload and anything that triggers a route change / push. Both SSR and client-side fetch do things their own way.

##### Further Reads:

1. https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs#pre-rendering-with-default-data
2. https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing

Comment: So if I understand correctly, leaving out SEO for a moment, the main bonus from SSR for the purpose of displaying a page in the user's browser is that the page will display quicker, having been generated server-side (so that the page HTML is sent from the get-go) and sent to the user, instead of taking time rendering on the user's machine, correct? From then on, the app will behave exactly like a React application in-browser?

Comment: Yes. Displaying quicker for SSR will now be dependent on the server's speed and also the network speed of the request. But yeah, unlike CSR, the users will be guaranteed to see the content on first load for SSR.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this question, as the best way to take advantage of Next.js server-side rendering while using React hooks extensively will vary depending on your specific needs and preferences. However, some tips on how to achieve this include:

**1.** Try using the Next.js client and server libraries together. The Next.js client library allows you to use Next.js features in your React applications, while the Next.js server library allows you to use Next.js to rendering your applications on the server. This can be a great way to take advantage of both Next.js' server-side rendering capabilities and React's hooks feature.

**2.** Use react-router-dom for routing. react-router-dom is a popular routing library for React that also supports server-side rendering. This can be a good choice for applications that need to use Next.js' server-side rendering capabilities as well as router functionality.

**Here is the small example. I hope it would help you.**

```
import React from 'react';

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';


const Page = () => {

 const router = useRouter();

 const { id } = router.query;

 return <p>Post: {id}</p>;

};

export default Page;
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit on why you'd recommend react-router-dom for routing? I'm asking because next.js has its own routing mechanism which I imagine it's optimised for (the `pages` dir), which supports both server-side rendering and static generation.

Comment: There's no point in using RRD on Next.js. You will only increase the bundle size by adding an extra/unneeded dependency. Not to mention you will also overcomplicate things. Next.js' built-in routing is more than enough.

Comment: @p-sad Both React Router DOM and NextJS default routing has its own advantages. React Router DOM is a library specifically for routing in React applications, while NextJS default routing is a general router that can be used in any kind of web application. React Router DOM offers a more traditional routing approach, while Next.js provides out-of-the-box support for server-side rendering and automatic code splitting & has a larger community and ecosystem, making it a more established choice for development.

Comment: @p-sad React Router DOM is more lightweight and modular, making it a better choice for smaller projects or those looking for more flexibility. But at the end its always depends on individual preferences and project needs. The best way to decide which one is better for your project is to try them both out and see which one works better for you.